# Failled to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node' MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor, semantic-ui

I am using the official semantic ui package for my Meteor web app and getting this error whenever I try and navigate through the vertical menu. This is causing my flowrouter routes to act wonky and not display. Thus, killing my mobile experience :(. But everything works perfect on desktop.

```
Error: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': 
The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
```

The template:

```
<template name="_nav">
  <div>
    <div class="ui grid large menu computer only">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="/cook.png" href="/">
      </div>
      <a href="/" class="item {{isActiveRoute name='home'}}">
        Home
      </a>
      <a href="/aboutus" class="item {{isActiveRoute name='aboutus'}}">
        About Us
      </a>
      <a href="/team" class="item {{isActiveRoute name='team'}}">
        Team
      </a>
      <a href="/contacts" class="item {{isActiveRoute name='contacts'}}">
        Contacts
      </a>
      <div class="ui large right menu">
        {{#if isInRole 'admin'}}
        <a href="/admin" class="item {{isActiveRoute name='admin'}}">
          Admin
        </a>
        {{/if}}
        <a class="ui item">
          {{> loginButtons}}
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="ui grid secondary menu mobile tablet only">
    <div class="ui container">
      <a class="item toggle-menu">
        <i class="big sidebar icon"></i>
      </a>
      <div class="ui sidebar vertical menu">
        <a href="/" class="item {{isActiveRoute name='home'}}">
          Home
        </a>
        <a href="/aboutus" class="item {{isActiveRoute name='aboutus'}}">
          About Us
        </a>
        <a href="/team" class="item {{isActiveRoute name='team'}}">
          Team
        </a>
        <a href="/contacts" class="item {{isActiveRoute name='contacts'}}">
          Contacts
        </a>
        {{#if isInRole 'admin'}}
          <a href="/admin" class="item {{isActiveRoute name='admin'}}">
          Admin
          </a>
        {{/if}}
      </div>
        <div class="ui secondary right menu">
          <a class="ui item">
            {{> loginButtons}}
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Events:

```
Template._nav.events({
  'click .toggle-menu': function () {
    $('.ui.sidebar')
      .sidebar('toggle');
  }
});
```

Routes (FlowRouter):

```
FlowRouter.route( '/' , {
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render( '_app', {
      nav: '_nav',
      content: 'home',
      footer: '_footer'
    });
  },
  name: 'home'
});

FlowRouter.route( '/AboutUs' , {
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render( '_app', {
      nav: '_nav',
      content: 'aboutus',
      footer: '_footer'
    });
  },
  name: 'aboutus'
});

FlowRouter.route( '/Team' , {
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render( '_app', {
      nav: '_nav',
      content: 'team',
      footer: '_footer'
    });
  },
  name: 'team'
});

FlowRouter.route( '/Contacts' , {
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render( '_app', {
      nav: '_nav',
      content: 'contacts_list',
      footer: '_footer'
    });
  },
  name: 'contacts'
});

FlowRouter.route( '/Admin' , {
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render( '_app', {
      nav: '_nav',
      content: 'admin',
      footer: '_footer'
    });
  },
  name: 'admin'
});
```

CSS (if it matters):

```
.ui.menu .active.item {
    background-color: #E0F1FF !important;
    color: Black !important;
}

.ui.dropdown.item {
  padding: 0;
}

.ui.dropdown.item:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00) !important;
}

.ui.menu {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Again, this error only shows whenever I try and navigate with the vertical menu. I am also using the sach:db-admin package which is yogibens:admin package but for FlowRouter. Which uses twbs:bootstrap for styling. This might be causing some issues but I am unsure.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a container ( or  etc) around {{#each}} or {{#if}} fields. Theres a bug with issues reported on meteor's github page. Something along the lines of replacing blocks.

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2373